# joining merge multiple dataframes without matching index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a complete data set that looks like this:
pandas==1.1.5

```
all_data_set = [
        ('A','Area1','AA','A B D E'),
        ('B','Area1','AA','A B D E'),
        ('C','Area2','BB','C'),
        ('D','Area1','CC','A B D E'),
        ('E','Area1','CC','A B D E'),
        ('F','Area3','BB','F'),
        ('G','Area4','AA','G H'),
        ('H','Area4','CC','G H'),
        ('I','Area5','BB','I'),
        ('J','Area6','AA','J L'),
        ('L','Area6','CC','J L'),
        ('M','Area5','BB','M')
        ]
all_df = pd.DataFrame(data = all_data_set, columns = ['Name','Area','Type','Group'])

 Name   Area Type    Group
0     A  Area1   AA  A B D E
1     B  Area1   AA  A B D E
2     C  Area2   BB        C
3     D  Area1   CC  A B D E
4     E  Area1   CC  A B D E
5     F  Area3   BB        F
6     G  Area4   AA      G H
7     H  Area4   CC      G H
8     I  Area5   BB        I
9     J  Area6   AA      J L
10    L  Area6   CC      J L
11    M  Area5   BB        M
```

From this data set I created 3 df's grouped by Type:

```
aa_df = all_df.loc[all_df['Type']=='AA']
aa_df = aa_df.rename(columns={'Group':'AA group'})
bb_df = all_df.loc[all_df['Type']=='BB']
bb_df = bb_df.rename(columns={'Group':'BB group'})
cc_df = all_df.loc[all_df['Type']=='CC']
cc_df = cc_df.rename(columns={'Group':'CC group'

 Name   Area Type AA group
0    A  Area1   AA  A B D E
1    B  Area1   AA  A B D E
6    G  Area4   AA      G H
9    J  Area6   AA      J L

   Name   Area Type BB group
2     C  Area2   BB        C
5     F  Area3   BB        F
8     I  Area5   BB        I
11    M  Area5   BB        M

   Name   Area Type CC group
3     D  Area1   CC  A B D E
4     E  Area1   CC  A B D E
7     H  Area4   CC      G H
10    L  Area6   CC      J L
```

My Goal is to Join them following these rules:

1. All Members are grouped by matching Area . ie Area1 has Names A B D E
2. AA Members are only Type = AA . ie of A B D E only A and B are AA Type
3. CC Members are only Type = CC
4. BB Members are always single and are also AA and CC Members

The resulting df should look like this

```
       Name   Area Type All Members AA Members CC Members
0     A  Area1   AA     A B D E        A B        D E
1     B  Area1   AA     A B D E        A B        D E
2     C  Area2   BB           C          C          C
3     D  Area1   CC     A B D E        A B        D E
4     E  Area1   CC     A B D E        A B        D E
5     F  Area3   BB           F          F          F
6     G  Area4   AA         G H          G          H
7     H  Area4   CC         G H          G          H
8     I  Area5   BB           I          I          I
9     J  Area6   AA         J L          J          L
10    L  Area6   CC         J L          J          L
11    M  Area5   BB           M          M          M
```

Im lost on how to join the 3 types of DFs since I don't have a shared index between the 3 , I was thinking I need some type of `isin` to look back at the `all_df` and reference the group. But the group is just like you see it, its names separated by spaces so I think I need to convert that to a list maybe?

Is there a way to do this using pandas or will I need a series of loops and lookups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think you don't need your grouped dfs. You can compute your members with `groupby` then use the created df to lookup AA and CC members. Finally fill NA values with `Name`:

```
import pandas as pd

all_data_set = [
        ('A','Area1','AA','A B D E'),
        ('B','Area1','AA','A B D E'),
        ('C','Area2','BB','C'),
        ('D','Area1','CC','A B D E'),
        ('E','Area1','CC','A B D E'),
        ('F','Area3','BB','F'),
        ('G','Area4','AA','G H'),
        ('H','Area4','CC','G H'),
        ('I','Area5','BB','I'),
        ('J','Area6','AA','J L'),
        ('L','Area6','CC','J L'),
        ('M','Area5','BB','M')
        ]
all_df = pd.DataFrame(data = all_data_set, columns = ['Name','Area','Type','Group'])

members_df = all_df.groupby(['Area', 'Type']).agg({'Name': list})
#print(members_df)

def get_members(row, typ):
    try:
        return " ".join(members_df.loc[(row['Area'], typ), 'Name'])
    except KeyError:
        return

all_df['AA members'] = all_df.apply(lambda x: get_members(x, 'AA'), axis=1)
all_df['CC members'] = all_df.apply(lambda x: get_members(x, 'CC'), axis=1)

# filling na values
all_df.loc[all_df['AA members'].isna(), 'AA members'] = all_df['Name']
all_df.loc[all_df['CC members'].isna(), 'CC members'] = all_df['Name']

print(all_df)
```

Output:

```
   Name   Area Type    Group AA members CC members
0     A  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
1     B  Area1   AA  A B D E        A B        D E
2     C  Area2   BB        C          C          C
3     D  Area1   CC  A B D E        A B        D E
4     E  Area1   CC  A B D E        A B        D E
5     F  Area3   BB        F          F          F
6     G  Area4   AA      G H          G          H
7     H  Area4   CC      G H          G          H
8     I  Area5   BB        I          I          I
9     J  Area6   AA      J L          J          L
10    L  Area6   CC      J L          J          L
11    M  Area5   BB        M          M          M
```

Comment: Works great cool use of lambda